# Pipeline semantics aren't propagated into Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I use the following command to run a pipeline.

```
.\Find-CalRatioSamples.ps1 data16 `
    | ? {-Not (Test-GRIDDataset -JobName DiVertAnalysis -JobVersion 13 -JobSourceDatasetName $_  -Exists -Location UWTeV-linux)}
```

The first is a custom script of mine, and runs very fast (miliseconds). The second is a custom command, also written by me (see https://github.com/LHCAtlas/AtlasSSH/blob/master/PSAtlasDatasetCommands/TestGRIDDataset.cs). It is very slow.

Actually, it isn't so slow processing each line of input. The setup before the first line of input can be processed is very expensive. That done, however, it goes quite quickly. So all the expensive code gets executed once, and only the fairly fast code needs to be executed for each new pipeline input.

Unfortunately, when I want to do the ? { } construct above, it seems like PowerShell doesn't keep the pipe-line as it did before. It now calls me command a fresh time for each line of input, causing the command to redo all the setup for each line.

Is there something I can change in how I invoke the pipe-line? Or in how I've coded up my cmdlet to prevent this from happening? Or am I stuck because this is just the way Where-Object works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working as designed. You're starting a new (nested) pipeline inside the scriptblock when you call your command.

If your function is doing the expensive code in its `Begin` block, then you need to *directly* pipe the first script into your function to get that advantage.

```
.\Find-CalRatioSamples.ps1 data16 | 
    Test-GRIDDataset -JobName DiVertAnalysis -JobVersion 13 -Exists -Location UWTeV-linux |
    Where-Object { $_ }
```

But then it seems that you are not returning the objects you want (the original).

One way you might be able to change `Test-GRIDDataset` is to implement a `-PassThru` switch, though you aren't actually accepting the full objects from your original script, so I'm unable to tell if this is feasible; but the code you wrote seems to be retrieving... stuff(?) from somewhere based on the name. Perhaps that would be sufficient? When `-PassThru` is specified, send the objects through the pipeline if they exist (rather than just a boolean of whether or not they do).

Then your code would look like this:

```
.\Find-CalRatioSamples.ps1 data16 | 
    Test-GRIDDataset -JobName DiVertAnalysis -JobVersion 13 -Exists -Location UWTeV-linux -PassThru
```

Comment: I'd not heard of the PashThru parameter before - seems like a bit of a grab-bag, but looks good. Here is an older blog post on it for those that come to this question later: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/18/use-the-powershell-passthru-parameter-and-get-back-objects/